# Center an absolute element below a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to center a pargraph below a div (could be a square image for the matter). I understand that the easiest way to do it is to contain both the div and the text below it in a single container and use `text-align`, but in this instance I have a limitation where I cannot let the small image be contained in a container wider than that image.

Without centering the text it looks like this:

[image]

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="block"></div>
<p class="label">This text is a bit long</p>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 5rem;
}
.block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px
}

.label {
  
}
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/omerh3/pen/oNqVjvV

The reason why I cannot let the image be in a container is that I'm using ReactFlow where the handles should connect to the sides of the image without a gap. If I put the image and the text inside a div, the div will take the width of the text and thus it will naturally be wider than the image.

I tried centering the text below the image with absolute positioning, but with different paragraphs sizes, it won't be persistent in the center. Is there a away to achieve this without inserting the image/square and the text inside one div?

One last thing: the width of the image if constant, for example 100px

Comment: How about calculate a width of square image and set the half of that width to `margin-left` of the paragraph ?

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately, it also has to take into account the paragraph width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this is to get the coordinates of your two elements and then add margin-left: to adjust the position of the span

```js
let divOffsets = document.getElementById('a').getBoundingClientRect();
let divRight = divOffsets.right;
let divLeft = divOffsets.left;
console.log(divLeft,divRight)

let spanOffsets = document.getElementById('b').getBoundingClientRect();
let spanRight = spanOffsets.right;
let spanLeft = spanOffsets.left;
console.log(spanLeft,spanRight)

let divCenter = divLeft + divRight / 2
console.log(divCenter)

let offset = divCenter - (spanLeft + spanRight / 2) 
offset = offset + "px"

document.getElementById('b').style.marginLeft = offset;
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5rem;
  border:solid 1px red;
  position:relative;
}
.block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  
}

span{
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'a'class="block"></div>
<span id = 'b' >1234</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this??

```css
body {
  padding: 5rem;
}
.block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin:0 auto;
  
}

p.label {text-align: center}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<p class="label">This text is a bit long</p>
```

Comment: Oh I think it could be great but it's not recognized in React for some reason I'm trying to find out why

Comment: I think it's not supported in HTML5

Comment: I edit the answer, try above code on your css see if that works for you.

Comment: This is not a good answer.  It forces both the block and text to the middle of the page.  A better answer will position the span relative to the block.  See other answer

Comment: You're right that it's working, I didn't explain my question well enough, in my case I must use absolute positioning to take the text out of the document flow, I should edit my question thanks a lot anyhow

Comment: @DCR well I'm asnwering base on the provided information. you're definitely right on position using script no doubt about that. I am not sure exactly his code so i just answer base on the code given and condition he have. I will gladly erase this answer if this is the wrong way of approaching to center elements.